# .manifest file and @font-face, iOS device, how to make it work? or graceful fallback?

Tags: ios, web-applications, browser-cache, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I am developing a web app.
Primarily for use on iPad mini.
Saving webpage to home screen for easy access by the user.

There are a number of fonts that I want to use that I am including via the @font-face CSS rule.

In the event that a user isn't connected to the internet, I still want the app to display properly, so I've included a .manifest file that asks the device to download all necessary resources. Some of these resources include .ttf and .otf typefaces.

Up until now, the .manifest file has worked famously in allowing me to store on the user's device, any necessary documents and image resources. While working my way through my directories of files I've now arrived at my fonts folder. As soon as I include a .ttf or .otf file in my .manifest file and try to open the app while disconnected from the internet, the iPad tells me that it cannot connect to the internet and thus cannot open the app. I hit retry and it loads the document but it is a big cascade of elements, totally un-styled, and generally doesn't work at all. In short, unacceptable.

It looks to me that including a .ttf or .otf file type breaks the .manifest file for some reason. Does anybody know how to make this work?

If I simply don't include the .ttf or .otf files in the manifest document, even when I am connected to the internet it doesn't display the typefaces for some reason. So it seems to me that the .manifest document really takes control of what the user sees and what he doesn't. Is there a way to just use standard fonts as a fallback (currently have implemented and working), but also if the user is connected to the internet allow the display of the fonts included by the @font-face rule?

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

@idbehold thanks for your response. Here is how my .manifest file reads:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
index.html
style.css
beforethegame.js
gameplay.js
glow.js
jquery.form.js
jquery.min.js
quiz.js
mobiletouch.js
images/arrow-left.png
images/arrow-right.png
images/chalk-apple.png
images/chalk-clock.png
images/chalk-pin.png
images/chalk-sound.png
images/full-screen-map-1.jpg
images/game-header.png
images/infinity-wave.gif
images/ipad-prize.png
images/kenshoo-logo.png
images/kenshoo-wave-animation.gif
images/legend-letter-a.png
images/legend-letter-b.png
images/legend-letter-c.png
images/legend-letter-d.png
images/legend-letter-e.png
images/legend-letter-f.png
images/legend-letter-g.png
images/legend-letter-h.png
images/legend-letter-i.png
images/legend-letter-j.png
images/Maximize-01.png
images/Minimize-01.png
images/pin.png
images/pin-1.png
images/property-map-bare-1.jpg
images/pull-tab.png
images/quiz-submit-button-1.png
images/second-prize.png
images/logos/admarketplace-logo.png
images/logos/boostctr-logo.png
images/logos/brighttag-logo.png
images/logos/centuryinteractive-logo.png
images/logos/conductor-logo.png
images/logos/covario-logo.png
images/logos/datapop-logo.png
images/logos/gearylsf-logo.png
images/logos/pmdigital-logo.png
images/logos/ramimeiri-logo.png
images/logos/resolutionmedia-logo.png
images/logos/shoutlet-logo.png
images/logos/yahoo-logo.png
images/logos/zenya-logo.png
images/logos/homescreen-icon.png
images/logos/K8-1.png
images/logos/k8-animation.gif
images/logos/k8-logo.png
Fonts/ProximaNova-Reg.ttf
Fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.ttf
Fonts/2810B1_0_0.ttf
Fonts/Chalkduster.ttf
Fonts/digital-7.ttf
Fonts/KRM63.ttf

NETWORK: \n*\n
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your appcache manifest file?

Comment: @idbehold I've added that .manifest doc's contents to the post! Thanks!

Comment: Is the `NETWORK: \n*\n` part intentional? As in, are the slash and `n` characters actually in the file when viewing it in a text editor?

Comment: It should look like: `NETWORK` followed by a line break followed by `*`

Comment: @idbehold yes, I added it in - my understanding is that is a "catch-all" to include all files from the server if available.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to make sure that when you open your manifest up in a browser you aren't actually seeing `\n`.

Comment: How large are your font files? Browsers have limits to appcache storage size, I believe most limit to about 5mb

Answer (score 0):

try this @font-face implementation

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-weight: 300%;
}
```

for more information check out this example https://github.com/ttibensky/BulletProof-font-face-implementation